# Expand a table based on JSON string present in a SQL table

Tags: json, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

We've got a usecase to display a grid in power bi dashbord which contains a JSON obejct in one of its column. The JSON data will based on another column value.

Based on the category selection, the JSON content should be expanded to table(always one row, multiple columns).

[image: Table Snapshot]

Please find the table below.

Answer (score 1):

Select the JsonData Column, select the Transform TAB and click Parse/Json.
[image]

Result is your text becomes records. Now on the right of your JsonData Column you have the dubble arrow, click on it. You do not need the prefix of original name so unselect checkbox. Click OK.

[image]

Now you went on level deeper (your column changed to DynamicProperties). Click the dubble arrow again.

End result is the table with all propoerties as in your Json.

[image]